# Attachment gets renamed in outlook with .dat extension

Tags: php, outlook, email-client

I'm sending email with attachment(pdf) through PHP. It works fine if I check it from web or thunder bird, but in outlook the attached file gets renamed to:

```
filename.pdf_.dat
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: you'll need to show us some code, we're not magicians...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDF attachments are changing to unusable DAT files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194447/pdf-attachments-are-changing-to-unusable-dat-files)

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. From the tested I made, it is not an Outlook issue. This has to do with the receiving server email probably. I'm still digging though.